# How can I give my male characters long hair?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is my vampire character.

[image: male vampire character with short hair]

I would like for him to have long hair going down his back, like Kain from BloodOmen or Kabito Kai from Dragonball Z, but all the default hairs are short.

Is there any way I can make him male, but still give him long hair?

Comment: I don't agree this is off-topic. While some mods are definitely there, it's totally possible that desirable effect also achievable by some other means - may be some combinations of character customization options or some console command.

Comment: @arghtype I don't fully agree with your reasoning: the idea that the changing of hairstyles, deviating from what vanilla allows for, *might* be possible using console commands or .ini tweaks is just as assuming as thinking only mods allow for this. I mean, both sides are arguing the germaneness of the question based on what assumed answers entail. However, it's true this question doesn't specifically ask for external software, so it shouldn't have been disputed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Are you interested in using mods to achieve the look you want?

Use [ApacheSkyHair](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/10168/) mod, and you should find a longer hairstyle you like for your character.

Comment: For one you have to manually install the mod and I hate manually with a deep deep passion.
I can never seem to do it right and put the mod in the correct file.
Secondly non of those style was what I'm looking for.
I was looking for something more like the following.
https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/1/12/KibitoKaiNV.png/revision/latest?cb=20100424162026

https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/legacyofkain/images/c/c9/Kain_screen4.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130610230220

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can change the appearance of your character, one which is 'official', and one which is a console hack.

If you have the Dawnguard expansion, you can go to see Galathil in The Ragged Flagon in Rifton, who will allow you to change your character's appearance for 1000 gold.

If you don't want to do this, and are OK with messing about in the console [PC only] then drop to console and then type *showracemenu* - you'll be able to make any changes you want. Just don't go mad with the changes [i.e. don't change race], since you can mess things up here. It's better, I feel, and safer, to go the 'official' route and consult Galathil.

Comment: Since the OP mentions 'the default hairs', I assume this is something they tried already. I interpret the problem to be the lack of a proper hairstyle in the vanilla game. And in case of `showracemenu`, re-enable your racial trait after making edits using the console.

Comment: @Joachim you may be right. OK, well, maybe my answer will still help someone else if this is not what the OP wanted.